# Azure Repo - how do I organize tags into folders

Tags: azure, directory, tags, devops, repo

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to organize tags into folders, on Azure Repos.
I've seen somewhere this image, and I would like to implement something like that.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? If I try to manually add a tag like 'folder1\tag1' it doesn't accept the backslash.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was pretty much simple. When you start typing "basefolder", Azure Devops auto validation for the text box, throws an error stating the path is invalid. What I didn't notice was that typing a simple character next to it, the error disappears.

So typing basefolder\tagversion does work in fact, and like a charm.

Nuno

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previous answer, I was able to create a folder by using the syntax "basefolder/tag_name", with a forward slash ("/") rather than a backslash ("\").

[Screenshot from the "Create a tag" interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrO5f.png)